# How find a set of integers y, z in the range 8.22 for the variable x?

Tags: python, variables, range

I have a problem with this task. I don't know if I wrote everything correctly in the code.

Python: How find a set of integers y, z in the range 8.22 for the variable x

My code:

```
for x in range (8, 22):
    for y in range (8,22,1):
        for z in range (8,22,2):
```

The result doesn't come out. Explain please!

Comment: Python: How find a set of integers y, z in the range 8...22 for the variable x

Comment: what do you mean by 'set' exactly ? you want to add them to python set

Comment: @kkkkkkkkkkkkk Example: x = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22.              
 y = 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21. z = 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22. The result should come out exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result doesn't come out.

Do you mean something like that ?

```
for x in range (8, 23):    print(x)
for y in range (9, 23, 2): print(y)
for z in range (8, 23, 2): print(z)
```

or maybe this ?

```
xlist = [x for x in range (8, 23)]
ylist = [y for y in range (9,23,2)]
zlist = [z for z in range (8,23,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly do you want to do, but considering your comment I tried something simple like the following:

```
x_list = []
y_list = []
z_list = []

for x in range (8, 23):
    x_list.append(x)
    for y in range (8, 22, 1):
        if y % 2 != 0:
            y_list.append(y)
            for item in range(len(y_list)):
                new_list = y_list[:7]
                y_list = new_list
        for z in range (8, 23, 2):
            z_list.append(z)
            for item in range(len(z_list)):
                new_list = z_list[:8]
                z_list = new_list
            
 print(x_list)
 print(y_list)
 print(z_list)

 output:
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
 [9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
 [8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
```

The code is not the best in the world, but it does what you want.